# What is the Roman Catholic Church doctrinal justification of its perceived opposition or support of the independence of Catalonia?

Tags: catholicism, biblical-basis, papacy

According to the [New York Daily News](http://www.nydailynews.com/newswires/news/business/latest-barcelona-mayor-calls-european-mediation-article-1.3542624),

> Vida Nueva (New Life) internet publication said the pope told Spain's new ambassador to the Vatican, Gerardo Bugallo, that *the Holy See is against all self-determination moves that are outside decolonization processes*.

(I have to say that although this is circulating in the news I don't know if there is an official statement from the Vatican).

In Spain though, some 400 priests [openly support](https://cruxnow.com/global-church/2017/10/04/priest-creates-appearance-mass-cover-catalan-independence-vote/) Catalonian independence.

I'm confused as to what business the Catholic Church would have in supporting or opposing an independence movement, unless it is related to its doctrine or the Bible.

Comment: I believe your question is on-topic and may very well be answerable according to the way you've framed it, but it seems to overlook the fact that the Vatican is not only (the headquarters of) a religious institution, but is also a nation state with (political) diplomatic relations with other nation states such as Spain.

Comment: As a Catholic, I have a similar question -- how is this the Pope's  business to comment upon in that way -- beyond the  historical facts that a variety of popes have put their fingers into European politics to a lesser or greater extent over the years.  Is your question about theology, Catholic doctrine,  scripture, or papal authority ...  or a mix of all?  When you ask "what religious basis" I am left somewhat at a loss, since religious basis is a vague term.

Comment: Is the actual quotation available?

Comment: @korvinstarmast I'm pretty sure that the Holy See is the name of the entity that carries on diplomatic relationships.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast Thanks. I was hoping for a direct quote of what Pope Francis said.

Comment: @KorvinStarmast I read the whole article, why?

Comment: This in fact is a complex question to answer due to the fact that the Vatican's Secretariat of State (dicastery of the Roman Curia) is divided into two sections: the Section for General Affairs and the Section for Relations with States. As the supreme leader of both a country (Holy See) and a world religion (Catholic). The Vatican does not have to have a doctrinal justification with the Catalina issue. This is a political question and would be dwelt within the Section for Relations with States.

Comment: @bradimus As was I, but I think that moral coward delegated it to a minion.

Comment: @ken graham It is a confusing issue because if Catholics hear the pope opposes independence then they will think that the Church opposes it as a matter of belief instead of separating the political arm of the Vatican from the matters of faith.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is seeking doctrinal justification for a political stance taken by the leader of a city-state (the Holy See).

Comment: It's sort of like asking, "What is the doctrinal justification for George Bush condemning the actions of Al Qaeda?" You *could* answer it, but I'm not so sure that's a realm of questions we should venture into. I could be wrong, though.

Comment: @Dan I think your Bush example is very poor because that has nothing to do with Christianity and Bush's doctrine would be a political doctrine. I asked about the Catholic Church doctrine so I think that is well within the scope of the site.

Answer (score 2):

> the Holy See is against all self-determination moves that are outside decolonization processes.

The Catholic reason for this is fairly simple. The people don't have a right to overthrow or revolt against legitimate rulers. The reason that decolonization processes are good is that they take away a nation's *unjust* claim to another sovereign peoples. IE, the colonized land was gained via unjust military action. Those are illegitimate rulers.

The [syllabus of errors](https://www.papalencyclicals.net/pius09/p9syll.htm), a papal encyclical listing statements to be condemned, contains this statement:

> 63. It is lawful to refuse obedience to legitimate princes, and even to rebel against them.

That is, the above statement is condemned by the Catholic Church as false.

Comment: There can be moves towards self-determination that are legal and not about decolonization. For example, if Scotland were to vote for independence from the UK, I doubt the Catholic church would be opposed to that.

Comment: Decolonization might not be the most exact terminology (although I believe I pulled this from the Catholic Encyclopedia on New Advent), but it's easy to see how Scotland's dependence upon the UK could be reasonably considered an unjust rule by the UK.

Comment: Given that it originates from when the King of Scotland was invited to take the throne of England, that's a bit of a stretch. And the same logic could be applied to Catalonia very easily. So is the interpretation that "unjust" rulers are "colonization" and so self-determination is allowed, and "just" ones are not and so rebellion is not allowed?

Comment: As I said, colonization may not be the right terminology here. However, the important distinction is between rebelling against legitimate vs illegitimate rulers.

Comment: A "move to self-determination" isn't necessarily a rebellion. If the Catalonians followed the rule of law, held a referendum, and then negotiated with the Spanish to achieve independence, would that be opposed by the Catholic Church?

Comment: @DJClayworth I got a notice today about some activity on this old thread, and noticed that I had not responded to your last question. Apologies for that. If it's still relevant, I'd say that if a group follows the rule of law to achieve independence, and the ruler allows it, then that would not be rebellion properly speaking. Presumably, the Church has no problem with this in principle.

Answer (score 1):

**What is the Roman Catholic Church doctrinal justification of its perceived opposition or support of the independence of Catalonia?**

I do not believe that this is a clear doctrinal subject matter at all.

This seems to be a of some sort private political statement, as it comes from the pope speaking to Spain's new ambassador to the Vatican at his accreditation to the Vatican. This in itself, indicates that this is indicative of Pope Francis’ personal political policy and is not a doctrinal issue at all.

This is most evidently a political and not doctrinal aspect at all, as Pope Francis clearly states that “***the Holy See is against all self-determination moves that are outside decolonization processes.***” The title of the **Holy See** is employed officially for diplomatic reasons of Vatican City.

> Although the Holy See is sometimes metonymically referred to as the "Vatican", the Vatican City State was distinctively established with the Lateran Treaty of 1929, between the Holy See and Italy, to ensure the temporal, diplomatic, and spiritual independence of the papacy. As such, papal nuncios, who are papal diplomats to states and international organizations, are recognized as representing the Holy See and not the Vatican City State, as prescribed in the Canon law of the Catholic Church. The Holy See is thus viewed as the central government of the Catholic Church. The Catholic Church, in turn, is the largest non-government provider of education and health care in the world. - [Holy See](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Holy_See)

Traditionally pope welcome new ambassadors that are accredited to the Holy See when they present their credentials ([The Credential Letters of the Ambassador of Spain to the Holy See, 02.10.2017](https://press.vatican.va/content/salastampa/en/bollettino/pubblico/2017/10/02/171002b.html)) and Pope Francis, I believe was pointing out a few personal observations at this moment in time.

Many may be confused as to what business the Catholic Church would have in supporting or opposing an independence movement, but it may simple be that of the Pope‘s personal views being expressed here. This is more evident as it is simply a statement on the at the moment H.E. Mr. Gerardo Ángel Bugallo Ottone became an ambassador of Spain to the Holy See.

Even the linked article itself points out that the pope was speaking to the new accredited ambassador to the Holy See and did not issue a doctrinal statement through the Congregation for the Doctrine of the Faith.

This is, in fact, a very complex question to answer due to the fact that the Vatican's Secretariat of State (Dicastery of the Roman Curia) is divided into two sections: the Section for General Affairs and the Section for Relations with States. As the supreme leader of both a country (Holy See) and a world religion (Catholic). The Vatican does not have to have a doctrinal justification with the Catalina issue. This is a political question and would be dwelt within the Section for Relations with States.

As for the 400 hundred priests supporting its' independence this could very well be a personal opinion of Pope Francis. I see no doctrinal issue involved in this subject matter, at least none have from forth from the Holy See and doubt any will be forth coming.

Historically popes has been involved in political issues of one nature or another for a variety of reasons. Foe example, Pope John Paul II negotiated peace between [Chile and Argentina](https://jp2online.pl/en/publication/john-paul-ii-the-peacemaker;UHVibGljYXRpb246ODQ=) in 1978. This was all done through the diplomatic channels of the Holy See (**Section for Relations with States**) and was in no way a doctrinal issue at all.

It would also be beneficial to this subject matter if we had the exact words pronounced by Pope Francis himself, without a third party interpretation!